# How to get free bash access on windows machine without admin rights?

Tags: scripting, bash

i would like to execute bash scripts at work but can't seem to find a decent way. My devices are my windows pc (no admin rights) and my Iphone. 
I want my scripts to run all day, so since my work pc is shut down during meetings and has no admin rights, this device is not suitable.
My iphone on the other hand would enable me to execute the scripts, but Ios policy forbids background activity for apps, so the script should run only for about 5 minutes (is that correct?).
For several reasons, i don't want to vpn to my homeserver either.
So do i need to rent a vserver for this?
Is there a way to get an online bash which executes in background for free?

Comment: Could you please split into two questions, one about the Windows PC only, and one about the iPhone only? Thanks!